# I'm using "npm install -g expo-cli" command so that I can install expo. But this is always the output. How to solve this?

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install, expo

[image: Error image]

This is always the output when I run the command.

Comment: It is asking for admin privileges. Have you tried running it twice in a row? For me sometimes it fails the first time but works fine on the second

Comment: It's always the same when I re-run the command.

Comment: @kahunaRN what does it mean that it needs admin priveleges?

Answer (score 1):

First uninstall your already installed node.

Install nvm 
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

While installing node using nvm, **use 8.11.2 version** cause it worked for me.

- nvm install 8.11.2
- nvm use 8.11.2

then do npm install -g expo-cli

Hope this helps.